# jQGrid Subgrid with edit delete option

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

How to enable add, edit button in jQgrid subGrid. I try to enable edit option in

SubGGrid. Please see my image below.

[image]

Is possible, Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ragesh Try Grid as Sub Grid, then you can have all the grid options.

Visit jqgrid demo page 
http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Expand Advanced there you can see the grid as subgrid demo